# best mysql data types for space reduction and performance increase

Tags: mysql

I search through google a bit and found a few decent articles, but not really what I needed. I'm trying to find the best data-types to use for:

1. data-type for 10 int length
2. data-type for 1 int length 0-9
3. data-type for int of 1 or 0
4. data-type for string of 32 chars
5. data-type for string of 255 chars

I guess my overall question is what data-types should I use to reduce space since the cost per GB is ~$6. Though I also don't want to sacrifice CPU performance just to save a byte.

Comment: For strings, is this fixed length or variable? For numbers, you should give a range of values. And trading storage for CPU is typical of compression eg InnoDB compressed format. You can't have it both ways

Comment: Six `*whole*` dollars per gigabyte? _Good lord_ your developers must be paid poorly if this is where you should be cutting costs.

Comment: @Matt Ball: [Hardware is Cheap, Programmers are Expensive](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive.html) However, we don't know where OP is based...

Comment: @Matt Ball: I know. The point has been made eloquently too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`int` or `bigint`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html), depending on just how big the 10-digit numbers are (`unsigned` if it makes sense)
2. [`tinyint`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html)
3. `boolean` (not nullable)
4. [`varchar(32)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html)
5. [`varchar(255)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html)

Comment: @user962449 thank you for the clarification. Just keep in mind: an `unsigned int`'s max value is `4294967295` (a 10-digit number) but that is not the _largest_ 10-digit number (`9999999999`).

Comment: You may want to add that `DECIMAL(10,0)` would need 5 bytes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html